# Can I use a regular 2512 SMD Resistor (0.001 ohm) for HLW8012 IC shunt Resistor

Tags: shunt

Can I use a regular **2512 SMD Resistor** for the shunt resistor as current sensing resistor for the HLW8012 power meter IC.
As per the data schematic, the manufacturer recommend to use a shunt resistor of **0.001 ohms**.
[image]

Comment: You *can* use it - nobody is stopping you but you won't get the accuracy you might desire and there may be nuances you didn't expect due to not using a shunt with kelvin connections.

Comment: The resistance of typical PCB  foil (1 ounce/square foot) is 0.000500 ohms per square, any size square. If you are not familiar with thinking about PCB foil resistance, you should use a 4-wire Kelvin resistor for accuracy.

Comment: I presume you are aware the whole circuit must be considered live? (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/354606/power-supply-architecture-for-energy-metering-ic-hlw8012)

Comment: What they said. Note that implementing a really good shunt resistor can involve technologies indistinguishable from magic. You can get thermionic effects, current flowing non linearly in the connections, .... . Much of this does not matter at say 1% accuracy but may well do at better than that.

Comment: @Huisman Yes, I'm aware of that but I still don't know what the  components connected to GND , Which GND?. Can you explain better to me?

Comment: @Khaalidi As Andy aka shows in linked answer with red coloured wires, line is connected to GND. So, the label GND =/= 0V but the label GND = 220Vac. And the label 5V = 5Vdc + 220Vac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed you can, at Sonoff they also wanted to save a few cents so they did this:

[image]

Image from [this site](https://tinkerman.cat/post/the-sonoff-pow/).

Note how the sense wires partly go **under** the shunt resistor.

Note that if the solder connection isn't good / reliable this can influence the total value of the shunt resistor + solder contacts. **That** issue is avoided when using a 4-terminal shunt resistor.

Note that at 1 milli ohm, it is easy to get a little extra resistance here and there.

As Andy aka comments: accuracy might be compromised.

Maybe that can (partly) be compensated for by a calibration.

It depends on what your priorities are (accuracy / calibration and cost).

Answer (score 2):

You can approximate a Kelvin connection with a 2 terminal resistor with a custom pad design that allows sensing of the voltage at the electrode of the resistor, rather than the pad of the board. [Analog](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/optimize-high-current-sensing-accuracy.html) has a good guide to the different approaches you can take - here are some of the possible arrangements that were tested.

[Optimize High-Current Sensing Accuracy by Improving Pad Layout of
Low-Value Shunt Resistors](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/optimize-high-current-sensing-accuracy.html)

The testing showed that trying to measure from a 2 pad arrangement, where the solder resistance is part of the sense element, produces significant errors once you get down to milliohm value shunts.

[image]

What is feasible is going to depend on what you can achieve in board resolution and the size of the terminals on the shunt resistor you are using, but a 2512 should allow you to use the following layout, which seems to have an acceptably small error.

[image]